# What does it mean "mulls action"?

Tags: meaning

> Spain **mulls action** over blame for E. coli outbreak

Source: [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/2011/05/30/us-germany-ecoli-spain-idUSTRE74T49020110530)

Comment: Couldn't find on Google `define:`

Comment: It's probably being used in this way because it provides a short snappy response.  In spoken English, you're more likely to hear "She's considering how to respond" rather than "she's mulling action", although both are grammatical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mull](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mull), in this case, means 'to consider'.

Thus:

> Spain considers action over blame for E.coli outbreak

Answer (score 0):

The OED gives meaning  "mull" 4.1.b. *trans*. *U.S.* To consider, ponder upon.

I don't recall having come across this transitive use (less surprising if it is a specifically US use) , but I am familiar with meaning 4.1.c: "to mull over : to turn over (an idea, etc.) in one's mind; reflect upon, think over, ponder."